# AngularJS how to use ng-model inside a custom directive tag, setting the controller dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel, angular-controller

I started in **Angular** recently, so I have some questions.

**My problem:** 
I created a directive that I will use in many 'pages' with different controllers in each situation, for example.
 Now I can set the controller dynamically well, this problem is solved!
 But, in each directive instance, I want to define what is the variable to be changed in the controller, like the `ng-model`. If I put directly inside the tag in template it works, but I need it dynamically.

**DIRECTIVE**:

```
app.directive('mySelectPicker', function () {
var ddo = {};
    ddo.restrict = 'E';
    ddo.templateUrl = 'js/directives/views/my-select-picker.html';

    ddo.scope = {};
    ddo.controller = "@";
    ddo.name = "controllerName";

    return ddo;
});
```

**MY-SELECT-PICKER.HTML**: 
**OBS1**: (ng-repeat is working perfectly with values in the times controllers' array)
**OBS2**: If I put the `ng-model` in the select tag, it works, but will be static!

```
<select>
    <option value="{{time.value}}" ng-repeat="time in times" >{{time.text}}</option>
</select>
```

**CONTROLLER**:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, moment){
    $scope.times = []; //array with the options
    $scope.val1 = '';
    $scope.val2 = '';
});
```

**USING THE DIRECTIVE**:

```
<my-select-picker controller-name="MyController" **ng-model="val1"**></my-select-picker>
<my-select-picker controller-name="MyController" **ng-model="val2"**></my-select-picker>
```

In resume, I need to define the `ng-model` in each `<my-select-picker>` to define what is the variable in the controller. How it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created isolated scope for your directive, so you can't access the parent scope your controller directive where directive tag has been placed, so you need to to pass the options list & model name to your directive.

Don't use `ng-model` as an attribute, because there is no any sense to ues `ng-model` attribute on directive element, as its not input element. Instead you could name that attribute as `model` & `list` then define that `model` & `list` attribute inside your isolated of directive. This both the property will be using `=` so that it can perform two way binding easily. Also you could use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` options rendering, because `ng-options` has ability bind object to `ng-model` on selection.

**HTML**

```
<my-select-picker list="times" controller-name="MyController" model="val1"></my-select-picker>
<my-select-picker list="times" controller-name="MyController" model="val2"></my-select-picker>
```

**Directive**

```
ddo.scope = {
   model: '=',
   list: '='
};
```

**my-select-picker.html**

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="l.value as l.text for l in list"></select>
```